# How read two first letters or number from a file, not the line?

Tags: c#

How can I write so this reads two first numbers and check if the text start with "00" and text stop on "99"

```
if (File.ReadLines(Filenametext.Text).First().Contains("00") && 
    File.ReadLines(Filenametext.Text).Last().Contains("99"))
```

This reads the line. I will read first 2 numbers or letters in the line.

Comment: I'd try with StartsWith() and EndsWith() instead of Contains() (if I understand what you mean) otherwise this single line "AA0099AA" will match your condition. BTW you don't need to read entire file twice...

Comment: Can you give some examples.  I'm not clear on what you mean by "and text stop on '99'".

Comment: Is the file content ASCII? You want the read the first two and last characters of the complete file?

Comment: yes i want to read first characters on the first line and the last one first charcters ? how ?

Comment: First characters of last line or last characters of last line?

Comment: First characters of both line.. First line i will read first two characters, Last line in CSV dokument i will read first two characters. two first characters on the first line and last line.